# What defines the dimension of a representation?

Tags: representation-theory

For example, if I have trivial representation of $S_3$, why does it have dimension 1? Why can't I take a vector space of dimension 2 and map all the vectors identically so I would have a representation of dimension 2?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can a trivial representation of dimension 2: it is the direct sum of two trivial representations, each of dimension 1. Often if a representation is a direct sum of two smaller representations, people focus on the smaller representations instead. If a representation has no direct sum decomposition, it is called indecomposable. The only indecomposable trivial representation has dimension 1 (or 0, but nobody cares about poor old 0).

Comment: Poor old 0))) But actually I don't like when ambiguous things like this are mentioned in the books without agreement.

Comment: Yup. It takes a while to get a feel for the culture in each area of math. If someone says **the** trivial representation, they mean the 1-dimensional indecomposable one. If they say **the** natural module for $S_3$, then you get to guess whether they mean the decomposable 3-dimensional module or the indecomposable 2-dimensional module (3=2+trivial).

Comment: Yeah I saw this thing with articles in the other question already, but I didn't pay much attention on articles when I read. So now I should.

Comment: @JackSchmidt I prefer to treat poor old $0$ even worse than you said. I call a representation indecomposable iff, whenever it is expressed as a direct sum of some representations, then it is isomorphic to one of the summands. The $0$ representation, being the direct sum of the empty family, is therefore not indecomposable.  Instead of being ignored, it is (justifiably) banished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A trivial representation does not need to have dimension $1$; if you have $S_3$ acting on a two-dimensional vector space, that would indeed be a trivial representation of dimension $2$. I think what's confusing you is that the trivial representation only needs to have dimension $1$ if it's an irreducible representation. In your example, there is an invariant subspace, (since any subspace will be invariant), so we can decompose the representation as two trivial subrepresentations, each of dimension 1. You can see that if we have a trivial representation of dimension $>1$, since any subspace will be invariant under our representation, we can always decompose our representation into one-dimensional trivial subrepresentations.